# Proving that $ \chi(G) = \omega(G) $ if $ \bar{G} $ is bipartite.

Tags: graph-theory, alternative-proof, coloring

I know that $ \chi \! \left( \bar{G} \right) = 2 $ and that $ \chi(G) \geq \alpha \! \left( \bar{G} \right) $, but how can I conclude that $ \chi(G) = \omega(G) $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it’s always true that $\chi(G)\ge\omega(G)$, so your real problem is to show that $\chi(G)\le\omega(G)$ if $\overline{G}$ is bipartite. Note that it need not be true that $\chi(\overline{G})=2$: the chromatic number of a bipartite graph is $1$ if the graph has no edges. In that case $G$ is a complete graph, and the result is trivial, so I’ll assume that $G$ is not complete.

Suppose that $\overline{G}$ is bipartite with parts $V$ and $W$. Without loss of generality we may assume that all isolated vertices of $\overline{G}$ belong to $V$, and that $|V|\ge|W|$. Clearly $V$ is a clique in $G$. Color each vertex of $V$ with a different color. Now observe that for each $w\in W$ there is at least one $v\in V$ such that $vw$ is an edge of $\overline{G}$ and hence such that $wv$ is *not* an edge of $G$, so that $w$ can be given the same color as $v$. Thus, $\chi(G)\le|V|\le\omega(G)$.

**Added 22 November 2021:**

The final step in the argument is incorrect: it is not necessarily true that $w$ can be given the same color as $v$. There might be a vertex $w'\in W\setminus\{w\}$ such that $v$ is the only vertex of $V$ adjacent to either $w$ or $w'$ in $\overline{G}$. Then the argument would make both $w$ and $w'$ the same color as $v$, but in fact $w$ and $w'$ are adjacent in $G$ and therefore cannot be given the same color. This error was noted in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3127355/proving-that-chig-omegag-if-the-complement-of-g-is-bipartite?noredirect=1&lq=1), and the accepted answer to that question also solves this one.

Comment: Simple and elegant! I just think that you meant to color each vertex of $V$ with a different color, instead of $G$. Also, I believe $|V|$ can't be lesser than $\omega(G)$ because $V$ is indeed the maximum clique of G. So, $\chi(G) \le |V| = \omega(G)$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @gcolucci: I did indeed mean $V$, not $G$; my finger must not have reached down far enough. You’re welcome!

Comment: Hey Brian, I think the question asks to prove $\chi(G)=\omega(G)$. As far as I can understand you have proven $\chi(G)\le \omega(G)$. Can you maybe explain a little more and clear my confusing...

Comment: @SayanDutta: You overlooked the very first statement in the proof: $\chi(G)\ge\omega(G)$ for all graphs $G$. This is obvious: if $C$ is a clique in $G$, each vertex of $C$ must receive a different color. However, as was pointed out in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3127355/proving-that-chig-omegag-if-the-complement-of-g-is-bipartite?noredirect=1&lq=1), there is a serious error in the second paragraph of the proof; the accepted answer to that question answers the question here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott oh yes! I understand. Thanks!

Comment: @SayanDutta: You’re welcome!

Answer (score -1):

suppose if $w \in W$ is adjacent to every vertex of V in G then  we cannot color that w with that and  cardinality of V and W are less tahn or equal to clique of G complement not exactly equal to . @gcolucci\in

Comment: Suppose $ \bar{G} $ bipartite with partitions $ V, W $. Suppose $ W = \{w\} $ and $ w $ adjacent to every vertex of $ V $. Then, $ V $ is clearly the greatest clique in $ G $ and $ w $ is isolated, so $ \omega(G) = |V| $. In order to color $ G $, we need $ |V| $ colors for $ V $ and pick any of these colors to color the isolated $ w $. Therefore, $ \chi(G) = |V| = \omega(G) $ and the result still holds. I might have misunderstood your point, though. I suggest you try do describe it a bit more precisely :)